# Can someone write or indicate a macro to create mark entries in a microsoft word document from a known list of words taken from another document?

Tags: indexing

I need to create an index for a thesis from a limited word list using a list from either another microsoft word document or an excel document

I tried using the Automark feature in microsoft, but the index created did not match the word list.